# How do you add a class to an anchor if its parent has the class xyz

Tags: jquery

How do you add a class to an anchor if its parent has the class xyz

I got so far...

```
if($("a").parents(".xyz").length > 0) {
addClass(".xyz")
};
```

obviously this isn't working otherwise I wouldn't be here asking :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do

```
$(".xyz a").addClass("xyz");
```

This will add the class `xyz` to all elements `a` having a parent of class `xyx`.

To be less ambiguous : if you want to add the class `xyz` to all elements `a` having a parent of class `abc`, use

```
$(".abc a").addClass("xyz");
```

If you want to be sure that there is a direct parent child relation, use

```
$(".abc > a").addClass("xyz");
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas This gain rarely matters and I personally prefer to keep the more readable syntax, which looks more like the one of CSS selectors.

Comment: I find the context paramater useful *only* if you've stored the parent element in a variable beforehand. `$('a', $parent)` is nicer than using `$parent.find('a')`. Otherwise, `$(".xyz a")` is much more readable.

Comment: @dystroy But it's more proper. You first want to do a query for all `.xyz` elements, and then search for anchors *within* those elements. `".xyz a"` performs a global query for anchors, and only then checks if these anchors are contained within `.xyz` elements (which is backwards). Separating the context from the target also has other benefits. With separated contexts, it's easier to spot when an context is used multiple times, and it's easier to sanitize such scenario (by creating a cached object `var $xyz = $('.xyz');`, and then replacing `".xyz"` with `$xyz`).

Comment: Beware to the burden your optimization puts on the readability of the code. Don't forget that most uses of jQuery could very easily be optimized away but that such a library is mostly used because it helps making a code easy to read and maintain. This being said, your comment can be an enlightening addition.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Readability is subjective. To me, contexts are always more readable than selectors with combinators. But I'm not arguing readability. Contexts are prefered because of the algorithms that take place internally (first query the context, then query the target within the context).

Comment: @dystroy My argument is that passing selectors that contain combinators (e.g. `.foo a`) to jQuery is not a good practice, in general. Some modern browsers may have optimized such queries, but it's still not the proper way - contexts should be queried first, then the target. As I said, readability is subjective. It's weird at fist, but now I'm used to it, and find it more readable.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Did a jsPerf test, the results are very interesting. With only 6 links on the page, the global selector variant was 27% slower. A normal page could have anywhere from 5 to 20 links on it. http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-vs-global. Think I might start using context more often!

Comment: @ChristianVarga (not a critic) Did you compare to `$(".abc > a")` ?

Comment: @ChristianVarga I did some "real world" testing on my Facebook start-page ([see here](http://pastebin.com/CiYwvApJ), you'll have to [load jQuery](http://pastebin.com/Jp4MmqZ2) first). The results are, `$( '.fbChatOrderedList a' )` takes around 5 milliseconds, and `$( 'a', '.fbChatOrderedList' )` goes up to 0.3 milliseconds which is more than 10 times faster. This is in Firefox, the performance difference is certainly significant.

Comment: Yeah Chrome seems to manage it better, but the css type selector is still slower. Also @dystroy, I didn't try that, but you can add your own test to the jsPerf so give it a shot and see if it's any different!

Comment: @dystroy I added the direct descendent selector, it's faster, but still not as fast as context. Very interesting!

Comment: @ChristianVarga, Sime I won't answer in details as this isn't a forum but thanks for your measurements and comments :)

Comment: This is getting a bit out of hand, but I also added `.find()`. To my surprise, it's actually the fastest out of the lot in the jsPerf tests.